# 1с-битрикс: наборы форм или что-то типа того

Tags: битрикс

Как в битриксе можно сделать так, чтобы пользователю выводилась форма, в которую он мог бы кнопочкой средствами *js* добавлять наборы полей для какого-либо типа сущности в бд, и таким образом создавать или редактировать сразу несколько экземпляров данного типа?

Например, во фреймворке *django* для этого есть "наборы форм" - в одной форме упаковывается произвольное количество групп полей для каждого экземпляра модели с последующей валидацией и сохраненим всех экземпляров — в одно действие.

Comment: Маловероятно что в битриксе это кому-то нужно.

Comment: Кажется в админке при формировании свойств инфоблока что-то похожее используется поэтому подумал что возможно есть такой штатный механизм но навскидку пока найти не удалось.